# Trying to use a string variable in serial .write in Python

Tags: python

I am communicating with a power supply through rs232. I can communicate no problem when I send for example:

```
port.write("\x31")
```

but if instead I have a string as a variable

```
teststring='"\\x31"'
```

(which prints out as "\x31")

and I try:

```
port.write(teststring)
```

it does not send the command to the supply. I have tried:

```
port.write(bytes(teststring,'utf-8'))
```

and

```
port.write(teststring.encode('utf-8'))
```

But it still is somehow not sending the same as just entering the text. I need to be able to change this variable, so I cannot just code the text in. 
Any help is appreciated!

Using comments below, I am now using an integer

testint=31
and if I print

chr(testint) I get a an odd box with 00 in the top row and 1F in the bottom. What I now need to be able to do is convert the 31 to 0x31, so I can use chr(0x31) which when printed produces 1. Hopefully the .write command will treat chr(0x31) the same as "\x31" ?

Answer (score 0):

`teststring` in your example is escaping the backslash; you have `"\\x30"`, instead of `"\x30"`. `"\x30"` is a length-1 string containing the byte 0x30; `"\\x30"` is a length-4 string containing the characters `\`, `x`, `3` and `0`. Dropping the first slash in `teststring` should behave exactly like using `port.write("\x30")`.

Comment: When I create the string I have to add the extra \ or it gives an error. If I print teststring to the screen, it is just "\x30"

Comment: Exactly; if you were doing it correctly it should print `0` (which is 0x30 in ASCII). What error do you get?

Comment: I create teststring from three strings actually. One that looks like this: ' "\\x' , one that is the number, and the final which is ' " '. If I leave off the second \ in creating the first string, I get an "invalid \x escape" error.

Comment: Ah, that's your problem. You can't combine escape characters like that; you probably want to use the `chr` function, which turns a number into the corresponding character; you would use `chr(0x30)` in your example.

Comment: Ok so I need to convert 30 from a string to number, then to a character?

Comment: I made 30 into an integer using int(), then used chr() on the result, it still is not sending the correct command.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the actual code you're running. It's impossible to help if we don't know what code you're actually running.

Comment: I have now an simpleint =1 and I was able to just use port.write(bytes(simpleint)) and that works. No need to jump through the hex value conversion I guess! Thank you